# jquery make able clicking on iframe only after x seconds

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
<iframe src="www.google.com" id="iFrame" ></iframe>
```

Now i want users to be able to click on this frame or on anything from this frame only after 10 seconds

Plus is possible so after 2 seconds for example after users clicked on frame to change frame height

```
<script>$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#frameID").animate({
    height: "720px"
  }, 1500 ); // how long the animation should be
});

</script>
```

I this script to run only after 2 seconds after they clicked on frame

Answer (score 1):

That's a very weird use case, but here's part of the solution to your problem:

Overlay an element with CSS `opacity: 0` over the iframe to keep it from getting the click. Remove the element after 10 seconds.

If the iframe isn't under the same domain, which I assume it isn't - you point to google.com, you can't listen to events inside of the iframe `contentDocument`. The iframe needs to be under the same domain as the parent document, or you need it to send out `window.postMessage` events with its internal state so you can alter the iframe's dimensions.

Comment: i can add a inside frame where will be google frame so it may work ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: if i make a frame for example

Comment: if i make a frame for example `<iframe src="/mysite.html"></iframe>`  wich will contain `<iframe src="www.google.com" id="iFrame" ></iframe>` will i be able to listen to events inside of the iframe

Answer (score 0):

First disable the iframe:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        var iframe = iframes[0],
            d = document.createElement('div');
        d.style.width = iframe.offsetWidth + 'px';
        d.style.height = iframe.offsetHeight + 'px';
        d.style.top = iframe.offsetTop + 'px';
        d.style.left = iframe.offsetLeft + 'px';
        d.style.position = 'absolute';
        d.style.opacity = '0';
        d.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
        d.style.background = 'black';
        d.setAttribute("id", "blockDiv");
        iframe.offsetParent.appendChild(d);
};
```

Then remove after 10 seconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#blockDiv').remove();
}, 10000);
```

**"Plus is possible so after 2 seconds for example after users clicked on frame to change frame height"**

This is not possible in your example. What you can do is change the width when the user moves the mouse over the iframe.